# Mouse position of PropertyGrid event

Tags: wxpython

I would like to implement a context/popup menu for a PropertyGrid and offer property-specific commands, e.g. "Export item". The menu would pop up when clicking on the name-field. I do not intend to change the popup menu that is readily provided for the value-field, e.g. Copy&Paste functionality.

PropertyGrid offers an event [wx.propgrid.EVT_PG_RIGHT_CLICK](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.propgrid.PropertyGridEvent.html). This lets me extract the PGProperty information (name/value) using

```
def OnRightClick(event):
    selectedName = event.GetProperty().GetName()
    selectedValue = event.GetProperty().GetValue()
```

However, this does not offer any location of the mouse event as [wx.MouseEvent](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.MouseEvent.html) would:

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_RIGHT_DOWN, self.OnRightDown)  
def OnRightDown(event):
    self.PopupMenu(self, event.GetPosition())
```

How can I determine the X/Y-location to open a popup menu on the name-field of a PropertyGrid?

The menu is essentially defined as

```
class PopMenu(wx.Menu):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(PopMenu, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        popmenu = wx.MenuItem(self, wx.NewId(), 'item')
        self.Append(popmenu)
```

Comment: I appreciated your edit to my answer, it did make it more rounded. Just for fun, I've made a minor adjustment to distinguish, which item was clicked and make it more obvious that the popup can be dynamic as well as static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a direct method of getting this information, so you'll have to improvise.
Try using a combination of `wx.GetMousePosition` and then use the windows `ScreenToClient` function, if you need the position relative to the window.

```
import wx
import wx.propgrid as wxpg
import datetime

class TestPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self,parent)
        self.SetSizer(wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL))
        self.pg = wxpg.PropertyGridManager(self,
                    style=wxpg.PG_SPLITTER_AUTO_CENTER |
                          wxpg.PG_TOOLBAR)

        # Show help as tooltips
        mychoices = ["1","2","3","4","5"]
        self.pg.SetExtraStyle(wxpg.PG_EX_HELP_AS_TOOLTIPS)
        self.pg.Append(wxpg.IntProperty("Number"))
        self.pg.Append(wxpg.StringProperty("Word", value="Some text"))
        self.pg.Append(wxpg.BoolProperty("Boolean"))
        self.pg.Append(wxpg.ColourProperty("Colour"))
        self.pg.Append(wxpg.MultiChoiceProperty("Choose","Choose",mychoices,value=["1"]))
        now_date = wx.DateTime.Now()
        self.pg.Append( wxpg.DateProperty("Date",value=now_date))
        self.pg.Bind(wxpg.EVT_PG_RIGHT_CLICK, self.OnRightClick)
        self.GetSizer().Add(self.pg,proportion=1,flag=wx.EXPAND)

        #define popup menu
        self.popupmenu = wx.Menu()
        self.top = wx.MenuItem(self.popupmenu, wx.ID_ANY, "Title")
        self.popupmenu.Append(self.top)
        self.popupmenu.AppendSeparator()        
        for text in "one two three four five".split():
            item = self.popupmenu.Append(-1, text)

    def OnRightClick(self, event):
        scr = wx.GetMousePosition()
        rel = self.ScreenToClient(scr)
        #print("screen Pos", scr, "Client", rel)
        #open popup menu at right click location - identifying the item clicked
        self.popupmenu.Delete(self.top)
        self.top = wx.MenuItem(self.popupmenu, wx.ID_ANY, event.GetProperty().GetName())
        self.popupmenu.Prepend(self.top)
        self.PopupMenu(self.popupmenu, rel)

class wxFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title)
        self.panel = TestPanel(self)
        self.Show(True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = wxFrame(None, 'Property Grid Test')
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]